# Pandas: Replace values within particular column of one dataframe based on a column in other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ipython

I am trying to compare if, the values in column 'Names' of 'df2' Dataframe are present in column 'Names' of 'df1'. I want to update the non-matching values in df1['Names'] with custom string 'Other'. I don't want to edit and any values in other columns.

Can someone please help me to get the expected result?

```
df1
    Names     Method
0   Ram       GET
1   Sham      POST
2   Ganesh    READ
3   Ramesh    GET
4   Deepak    POST

df2
    Names
0   Sham
1   Ram
```

Expected result of df1:

```
df1
    Names     Method
0   Ram       GET
1   Sham      POST
2   Other     READ
3   Other     GET
4   Other     POST
```

Comment: Would this work: `df1.loc[~df1['Names'].isin(df2['Names']), 'Names'] = 'Other'`?

Comment: It works..You are Awesome!!

Comment: @stephan, would you mind to turn your comment into an answer - so the question will not remain unanswered?

Comment: @MaxU: done as per your request. Just wasn't sure I fully understood the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) to check whether the values of one series or frame are in another one. To get a "not is in", simply negate the result with `~`:

```
>>> ~df1['Names'].isin(df2['Names'])
0     False
1     False
2     True
3     True
4     True
```

You can then use the result to [select](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label) the values to change, and to change these by assignment:

```
df1.loc[~df1['Names'].isin(df2['Names']), 'Names'] = 'Other'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [39]: df1.loc[df1.query("Names not in @df2.Names").index, 'Names'] = 'Other'

In [40]: df1
Out[40]:
   Names Method
0    Ram    GET
1   Sham   POST
2  Other   READ
3  Other    GET
4  Other   POST
```

NOTE: [@stephan's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46629363/pandas-replace-values-within-particular-column-of-one-dataframe-based-on-a-colu#comment80208597_46629363) is more idiomatic and most probably it'll be faster as well